# "Rent income" or "Rental income"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests

My understanding is that "rental" is a word implying that income is being received from a property one owns and leases to a tenant. "Rent" is used more in the sense of what a tenant pays a landlord.

I am looking specifically for a two or three word phrase to be used in a list of possible sources of income.

Which option is more correct?

> "rent income"

or

> "rental income"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither seems particularly natural to me. Personally, I'd recommend:

> Rental property income

Although according Google Ngrams, ["*rental income*" is the most popular](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rental%20income,%20rent%20income,%20rental%20property%20income&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) of the three.

Comment: +1 for *rental income* which is a standard term in the US on numerous forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use the most explicit form:

> Income from rent.

Or you could turn it around and specify the profession:

> Landlord income.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "rental" is the adjective for "income."  I reviewed other such pairings: "optical illusion" and "nocturnal animal" to come to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is to say that the correct term is

> **Rental income**

I believe that this is the term used on UK government tax forms (but do not have one available to check).

This is also confirmed by the following dictionary definitions (note the ones in **bold**):

> **rental<sup>[1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=rental&title=21st)</sup> *noun***
>   1. the act of renting.
>   2. **money paid as rent**.
>   3. **income derived from money paid as rent.**
>   4. a list of rent owed to a property owner by tenants; a rent-roll.
>   5. property available for renting.
>
> **rental<sup>[2](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rental?q=rental)</sup> *noun***
>   **an amount paid or received as rent**